# How to hold huge data in .NET in-memory

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure

I have almost 1 billion data in SQL Server which is hosted in Azure cloud. Which is the best way to retrieve it and hold in datatable so that the data can be used for some computation and processing. The thing is based on the user login, for each user we have to maintain separate sessions with this much data.
Currently we are facing performance & out of memory issues.

May I know any changes that can be done in cloud like app-service memory increase and is there any technical/logical method which render best performance in C#.

Comment: Do you _actually_ need that much data at the same time or can you work with a smaller subset and retrieve new data on the fly? Also, you should point out the _exact_ problem as this is currently not solvable without any further information.

Comment: Without know the problem in its entirety, it sounds like you should be performing the calculations on smaller buffers of the data.  Then calculating the the totals.  You could even save these buffer results with the operation so other users wouldn't incur the same cost.

Comment: Not sure about the situation in you app, but IF you have an application data in cloud, then design your Store procedure to return certain number of record in each call(Pagination). So that in memory will be able to hold it & by that time you can process already received data & can make another call to get next batch of data

Comment: If you need to hold it in a DataTable and you're running out of memory - get more memory. Otherwise revisit your need to hold it all in a DataTable.

Comment: Actually we need to use this data result to do some computations and the result set also would be this much larger dataset only .(say eg for doing simulation in demand forcasting application)